# Placing Ads after x amount of data entries

Tags: php

I want to place an advert after entries 4 and 12 if my database query comes back with over 13 results. If the results are less than 13 i would like to place just the one advert at 6.

How do i do this?

code for getting database results

```
@foreach($batsmen as $bat)

<h2>$bat->name<h2>
<p> $bat->age<p>
<p> $bat->team<p>

@endforeach
```

Comment: Is each `bat` considered one result here?

Comment: With what you have provided us, all I can suggest is to check the loop index

Answer (score 0):

You can solve it with a simple if condition and using the index of the foreach:

```
@foreach($batsmen as $i => $bat)
  <h2>$bat->name<h2>
  <p> $bat->age<p>
  <p> $bat->team<p>
  @if((count($batsmen)<13)
   @if($i == 5)
     <p>
     Advert
     </p>
   @endif
  @else
    @if($i == 3 || $i == 11)
     <p>
     Advert
     </p>
    @endif
  @endif
@endforeach
```

Remember, the index starts at 0.

Comment: I get a problem with this solution. Only the first part of your solution works even if the results are greater than 13

Comment: @dionarap Now it should work, it can be done in one if condition but just I don't realize right now which one.

Comment: Same error, the advert only shows after 6 no matter whether the results are less than or greater than 13

Answer (score 0):

The first and simplest solution comes to my mind is this.

```
$i=1;
@foreach($batsmen as $bat)

<h2>$bat->name<h2>
<p> $bat->age<p>
<p> $bat->team<p>
<?php
if($i==4 && count($batsmen>12))
{
    replace_ad();
}
if($i==6 && count($batsmen<12))
{
    replace_ad();
}
if($i==12)
{
    replace_ad();
}
$i++;?>
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

try using modulus  .

run a counter and take modulus, when its  0 for 12th record, it will display the ad

```
$i=0;
foreach($batsmen as $bat){
  <h2>$bat->name<h2>
  <p> $bat->age<p>
  <p> $bat->team<p>
   if($i % 12 == 0)
      echo 'ad'.$I;
    $i++;
}
```

PS: i am not familiar with this style of coding , so just take the concept of modulus . hope it heöps